# (How) can I configure ReSharper to accept a second spell checking language in comments, but not in code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, spell-checking, jetbrains-ide

I would like to set ReSharper to approve the following lines:

```
dynamic eggLayingMilkBearingWoollySow;
// Declares an egg-laying, milk-bearing woolly sow
// TODO: Deutsche Kartoffeln essen
```

But to warn at the following ones:

```
object deutscheKartoffel;
```

In short, ReSharper should only allow english dictionaries for names in code (variables, parameters, classes, ...) but also read from other dictionaries such as for German language when checking comments.

(How) is this possible? Thanks in advance.